# Can I write npm package in CoffeeScript?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, npm

I have used CoffeeScript for a while. Now I need to write a npm package, can I write it in CoffeeScript, or I should compile CoffeeScript into JavaScript?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196595/how-do-i-compile-coffeescript-before-publishing-to-npm

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that you write your package in coffeescript, but only publish it in javascript. I do it like this:

- coffeescript code goes in `src`
- code is compiled to `lib`
- `src` is committed to my git repo, `lib` is in my `.gitignore`
- `lib` is published to npm, `src` is in my `.npmignore`
- the `coffee-script` package is in my `devDependencies`

You can take a look at a simple package of mine, [refix](https://github.com/linus/refix), for inspiration:

- https://github.com/linus/refix
- `npm install refix`

Comment: I'll add that defining an `prepublish` task in your package.json that compiles your coffeescript is a handy way to automate this before your publish -- since we all forget to compile sometimes. See the npm `scripts` doc for more info: https://npmjs.org/doc/scripts.html

Comment: The one point I disagree with is keeping the lib folder in `.gitignore`. It is very handy to keep the lib folder in git so that people can reference your package via a git url.

Comment: If you have a postinstall task that compiles your coffeescript then you don't need to check in .js to `lib/` in your git repository, and can safely add it to ignore just as Linus suggests here. See - https://github.com/ilkosta/static-jade-brunch for an example of how you could use those hooks (as well as how you might possibly avoid a global install of coffeescript)

Comment: While this is probably the more sustainable approach and a good example of best practices, you can also check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/27813782/722758 for a more direct (if somewhat hacky) way to use coffeescript within an npm package.

Comment: Relevant issue in the Coffeescript repo: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/2216

Comment: @Linus i fail to see a .gitignore and a .npmignore in your repository, am i missing something?

Comment: @kroe so sorry, that's a bit awkward and quite hilarious. I had never added the files, since dot-files are ignored by the .gitignore... Silly me. Fixed now, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can write NPM modules in coffeescript, but in order for them to be usable by JS users they must be compiled to JS before you publish on NPM.

`package.json` makes this easy with their `prepublish` script hook which runs the specified script before you publish. Heres an example of a `prepublish` NPM hook in zombie.js

https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/master/package.json#L16

Answer (score 2):

If a lot of your modules have `coffee-script` in their `devDependencies`, it's useful to just globally install `coffee-script` instead of install it for each module (which takes much longer).

[coffee-build](https://github.com/aleclarson/coffee-build) is a global version manager for `coffee-script`.

Just add these 2 scripts to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-coffee-module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "coffee-build -v 1.11.x -b -o js src",
    "postinstall": "npm run build"
  }
}
```

Notice how `-v 1.11.x` is not an exact version, which allows implicit upgrades.

The only downfall is that users must `npm install -g coffee-build` before they can install your module.

Answer (score 1):

I have written npm packages in CoffeeScript from scratch. I encourage you to use CoffeScript for node as well as for the Browser. However, before you can use or publish your module, you have to compile the source CoffeeScript to JavaScript. That should not hold you back from using CoffeeScript, though.

Tip: While developing, use `coffee -cw yourfile.coffee` (command line) to watch the file for changes and compile on save.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure if it's the best approach, technically it *is* possible to write your package mostly in CoffeeScript.

Basically, you can write a JS file that simply wraps the `coffee` command, like so:

**bin/howl.coffee**

```
console.log 'Awwwooooo!'
```

**bin/howl.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var path    = require('path');
var exec    = require('child_process').exec;
var coffee  = path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee');
var howl    = path.resolve(__dirname, './howl.coffee');
var command = coffee + ' ' + howl;

exec(command, function(error, stdout) {
  if (error) { throw error };
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Running `node howl.js` (or simply `howl` when it's installed globally) will now output `Awwooooo!`. You can do things like `require` other CoffeeScript files and access arguments by passing them from the JavaScript "wrapper" to the CoffeeScript.

Anyway, there may be reasons not to do this, but it has worked for me so far so figured I'd submit this for an additional perspective.

For a simple example project using this technique, check out https://www.github.com/joshuabc/packdown.

Comment: For your specific example, there is no need to use exec. You can use require('coffee-script/register'), it registers a global handler for requires that automatically compiles any coffee dependency. Howerver that is not a good practice for a library since the global coffee-script can conflict with other versions

Comment: Previous example becomes: require('coffe-script/register'); var howl = require('./howl');

Comment: Good point Diego. Some more detail on that: `coffee-script/register` depends on [require.extensions](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_require_extensions) which is deprecated. According to nodejs.org: *"Since the Module system is locked, this feature will probably never go away. However, it may have subtle bugs and complexities that are best left untouched."* The feature is [unlikely to be removed from coffee itself](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/3692), but in my opinion the deprecation is a good reason to steer clear.