# How do I compile coffeescript before publishing to NPM?

Tags: coffeescript, package, npm

I wrote a simple module in CoffeeScript, but I want to publish the compiled JavaScript to NPM.  I don't want to manually run the `coffee` command each time, that's too much typing and I'll probably forget and publish stale js every now and then.

I know there's some combination of npm [package.json script hooks](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html) and CoffeeScript cli arguments that will do the trick, but I forget the particulars. How's it go again?

Answer (score 5):

A basic package.json setup for the [conventional directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13646337/407845) looks like

```
"scripts": {
  "prepublish": "coffee --compile --output lib/ src/"
}
```

If you also want to compile coffeescript before running tests, you likely want to pull the compilation step out as a reusable script:

```
"scripts": {
  "pretest": "npm run compile",
  "prepublish": "npm run compile",
  "test": "mocha",
  "compile": "coffee --compile --output lib/ src/"
}
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to setup `Cakefile` or `Makefile` to handle building and testing processes.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny worth noting for sure.  [Some folks](http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run) feel strongly that such a build tool is often unnecessary.  Node modules are often (ideally?) so small that build tooling beyond scripts is excessive.

Comment: @VasiliyBorovyak works for me with coffee-script 1.9.2.  Would you tell me a bit more about the problems you're having?

Comment: Works with latest coffee. Sorry for that. Can't upvote. Freaking SO says I can't revote unless the answer is changed .

Answer (score 1):

The `prepublish` script is considered deprecated later versions of [npm@4.0.0](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#deprecation-note). You should use `prepare` instead. There's another script that was introduced alongside the former `prepublishOnly`. They are similar but different, you can read more in the linked post.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "coffee --compile --output lib/ src/",
    "prepare": "npm run build && npm test",
    "test": "jest"
}
```

Comment: This did it for me, with node 15