# Automatically generating ambient module declarations

Tags: module, scripting, typescript

Given these 2 typescript files

*`api/Token.ts`*

```
interface Token { 
    code: string
}
export default Token
```

and *`index.ts`*

```
export * from './api/Token'
```

tsc 1.5 with the `--declarations` switch will generate two `.d.ts` files (with similar content)

*`api/Token.d.ts`*

```
interface Token { 
    code: string;
}
export default Token;
```

and *`index.d.ts`*

```
export * from './api/Token';
```

Running **grunt-dts-bundle** with the following options

```
    dts_bundle: {
        release: {
            options: {
                name: 'my-module',
                main: 'index.d.ts'
            }
        }
    }
```

will generate an ambient module declaration file  `my-module.d.ts` with the following content

```
declare module 'my-module' {
    export * from './api/Token';
}
```

However this declaration does not compile due to : `Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.`

How can I *automatically* generate an ambient module declaration for the two typescript files above ?

**EDIT**

Please follow latest updates on https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2262

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently written a [blog post](http://blog.charto.net/node/Publishing-TypeScript-based-modules-on-npm/) about this. To summarize, you can use [autodts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autodts) if you replace `index.ts` with `api.ts`, containing the following:

```
export {default as Token} from './api/Token';
```

Make sure `api.ts` is in the same place as the `api` directory (next to, not inside it).

Then you need a `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/api.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm install autodts",
    "postinstall": "autodts link",
    "prepublish": "tsc && autodts generate"
  },
  "typescript": {
    "definition": "index.d.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autodts": "~0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@lib/autodts-generator": "~0.0.1",
    "typescript": "~1.5.3"
  }
}
```

It's important that the package name `api` matches the file `api.ts` and directory `api`. This way both Node.js and the TypeScript compiler will look in the same places when using your package.

Finally, you need a `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "files": [
        "api.ts"
    ]
}
```

Now `npm install` will compile your package and produce a bundled `index.d.ts` file as defined in the `definition` setting in `package.json`.

To use your package, you can do something like:

```
/// <reference path = "api/index.d.ts" />

import {Token} from 'api';

class foo {
    key: Token;
}
```

You can use `autodts link` to keep the `reference path` up to date, check the blog post and/or autodts docs for that.

The resulting `index.d.ts` contains:

```
/// <reference path="index.ref.d.ts" />
declare module 'api/Token' {
    interface Token {
        code: string;
    }
    export default Token;

}
declare module 'api' {
    export { default as Token } from 'api/Token';

}
```

`index.ref.d.ts` and `api.js` are blank.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer and my apologies for the late reply, I was waiting to test TypeScript 1.6 which completely changes the deal. Your solution is the way to go for TypeScript < 1.6. For TypeScript 1.6, there are some details in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247

Comment: @BrunoGrieder https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages is really unclear. I've been reading pages upon pages of comments on github issues but cannot find an answer to this really simple question. With typescript > 1.6, should you want to, for example, write a library that uses the "inversify" module (typed), and then you also want to use inversify outside the library. How do you achieve that??

Comment: @David I never used inversify but you can find a boilerplate library [here](http://github.com/wadahiro/typescript-library-boilerplate) and some details I wrote [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221594/best-way-to-share-a-js-object-between-a-typescript-frontend-and-nodejs-backend/34225037#34225037) and somewhat similar near the bottom [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582275/using-an-external-typescript-library-within-a-typescript-internal-module/35588095#35588095)