# Best way to share a js object between a Typescript frontend and NodeJs backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm writing an application that uses Angular2 with Typescript as frontend, and NodeJS as backend. I've written a javascript object I wish to share between the frontend and backend. What's the most elegant way to do this?

My initial idea was to write a .d.ts for the frontend, and add a module.exports in the javascript file, so the backend could require('myobject').

While this works, this causes the browser to throw and exception that shows up in the browser console: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined'.

And I'd like to not pollute my console with needless error messages. So is there another, more elegant, way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "cleanest" way I know to do this is to write modular script on both ends and create a library of objects you want to share (so that the shared objects are defined in a single location)

### Set-up

Frontend: Typescript with either

- target ES6, module: commonjs + Babel  (requires Typescript 1.7)
- or target ES5, module: commonjs

bundled using webpack or browserify

Backend: ES6 (with --harmony flag on node) or ES5

### Library

Create a library, say `shared`, written in Typescript and create the exported Object class

```
export default class MyObject{ ... }
```

Make sure the library is compiled with `declaration: true` (in tsconfig for instance): `tsc` will generate the js + the typings (declarations).

In the `package.json` of the `shared` library, make sure the entry `typings` is set to point to the generated `MyObject.d.ts` file. If there are multiple objects; create an `index.ts` file that re-exports all the objects and point `typings` to `index.d.ts`

### Usage

Frontend: since you are now using modular JS/TS, import your object directly from Typescript

```
import MyObject from 'shared'
```

The typescript transpiler will automatically find the `.d.ts` definition from the `typings` entry of `shared`'s `package.json`.

Backend: simply `require('shared')`

Note: if there are multiple shared objects, do not use default exports in `shared`: they cannot be re-exported.