# Publishing Typescript 2.3 Modules to NPM for Angular 4 Consumption

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, typescript2.2

There are related instructions in [Writing NPM modules in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928253/writing-npm-modules-in-typescript)
, however it's dated and there are now a lot of different answers which may or may not work for Angular.  There's also a very good presentation by Jason Aden on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unICbsPGFIA&t=1284s) on how to publish Angular Components, but in this case I'm only interested in publishing vanilla typescript classes.

Comment: Just noting that Parcel is probably a better choice than rollup now, since it also supports tree shaking commonjs modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finished a prototype for testing this out.  I used code from [this article - creating npm modules written in typescript](https://medium.com/@nahush.farkande/creating-npm-modules-written-in-typescript-8d3cb4e65783) and the rollup suggestion from [Jason Aden's Packaging Angular Presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unICbsPGFIA&t=1136s).

Note that the `tsconfig-cjs.json` part of this is there so that in addition to supporting webpack and Angular, we also support commonjs + es5 workflows.

### Github Repository

[TS Module Producer Project](https://github.com/oleersoy/tsmproducer)

### Steps

#### Project Setup

Initialize the Project (The TS Module Producer)

```
mkdir tsmproducer
cd tsmproducer
# Initialize the project's package.json
npm init -y
```

#### Replace `package.json`:

```
    {
      "name": "tsmproducer",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Example typescript npm project supporting es6 modules via the module package.json attribute as well as commonjs",
      "main": "target/main/cjs/index.js",
      "types": "target/main/esm/index.d.ts",
      "module": "target/main/esm/fesm.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build-cjs": "rm -rf target/main/cjs && tsc -p tsconfig-cjs.json",
        "build-esm": "rm -rf target/main/esm && tsc -p tsconfig-esm.json && rollup target/main/esm/index.js -o target/main/esm/fesm.js",
        "build-all": "npm run build-cjs && npm run build-esm"
      },
      "keywords": [
        "typescript",
        "commonjs",
        "npm",
        "modules",
        "es6",
        "es2015",
        "publishing",
        "rollup",
        "treeshaking"
      ],
      "author": "Ole Ersoy",
      "license": "MIT",
      "devDependencies": {
        "rollup": "^0.41.6",
        "typescript": "^2.3.4"
      }
    }
```

#### Download dependencies

```
npm i
npm i -g rollup
npm i -g typescript    


# Make typescript source directory
mkdir -p src/main/ts
```

#### Create typescript compiler settings for es6 and commonjs

```
# tsconfig-esm.json

    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "declaration": true,
            "module": "es2015",
            "target": "es5",
            "rootDir": "src/main/ts",
            "outDir": "target/main/esm"
        },
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules"
        ]
    }

# tsconfig-cjs.json

  {
      "compilerOptions": {
          "module": "commonjs",
          "target": "es5",
          "rootDir": "src/main/ts",
          "outDir": "target/main/cjs"
      },
      "exclude": [
          "node_modules"
      ]
  }
```

#### Create typescript test exports:

```
# src/main/ts/printSubtract.ts

    export function printSubtract(...numbers: number[]) {
        console.log(`Subtracting the numbers: ${numbers.join(', ')}`);
    }

# src/main/ts/printAdd.ts

    export function printAdd(...numbers: number[]) {
        console.log(`Adding the numbers: ${numbers.join(', ')}`);
    }

# src/main/ts/index.ts

    export * from './printAdd';
    export * from './printSubtract';
```

#### Compile

```
npm run build-all
```

### Create a consumer project

```
mkdir tsmconsumer (TS Module Consumer)
cd tsmconsumer
npm init -y
npm i ../tsmproducer
```

#### Create a module consumer

```
touch index.ts
```

In `index.ts` try the following:

```
    import {printAdd, printSubtract} from 'tsmproducer';
    printAdd(1, 2);
    printSubtract(2, 1);
```

### Summary

- The FESM (Flat EcmaScript module) produced by rollup is exposed via `package.json's module` attribute.
- Typescript declaration files are produced and placed in the `target/main/esm` directory and exposed via `package.json's types` attribute.
- CommonJS module support is enabled via `package.json's main` attribute.