# Best practice in organizing NPM module exports in a typescript library project?

Tags: typescript, npm

I am writing a library package in Typescript to be published to the `npm` registry such that it can be used by various other projects.

I have followed the [publishing doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) to ensure that the `--declaration` option is true for `tsc` such that type definitions are exported as well in `*.d.ts` files.

The question I have is right now such exports are scattered in various folders and the consumers of my package are importing them like below.

```js
import { FooType } from 'my-test-pacakge/dist/src/foo/types';
import { BarInterface } from 'my-test-package/dist/src/foo/bar';
```

I am wondering whether this is acceptable as it looks messy. Should I write my own declaration file to organize them in a cleaner manner?

There are existing answers to similar questions suggesting [exporting the API through a general index.ts file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44617078/4993386). That sounds pretty legitimate to me but I am just wondering whether importing from the `dist` folder directly is considered bad practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most packages will prefer to export from 1 export point, so that the user of your libraries does not need to know *anything* about the directory structure of your package.

```
import { FooType, BarInterface } from 'my-test-package'.
```

A bonus benefit is that you can restructure the internals of your package without affecting the end-user, and it clearly delineates what the items are that you intend to be used by users of your package, and which are internal to your package.

So yes, I would agree that this is a best practice.

There are some packages that have additional namespacing, the `mysql2` package comes to mind that has two major exports:

```js
import { Connection } from 'mysql2';
import { Connection } from 'mysql2/promise';
```

But note that there's nothing like `dist` in here. `dist` is not meaningful to the end-user.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That definitely reinforces the idea of doing so for me. And I also encountered this blog which talks about the same topic in very succinct terms. https://betterstack.dev/blog/publishing-type-definitions-with-npm-package/