# How to point index file for npm package written in typescript

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a package written in typescript. Main module is located in `src` and is called `Popover.ts`. Main index file is called `index.js` and `main` field in `package.json` is pointed to that file. It has such content:

```
exports.Popover = require('./src/js/Popover');
```

Then in another package I try to include this plugin. I installed it with npm. And here issues come. In javascript everything works well:

```
const Popover = require('popover');
```

But when I try to import it in typescript file (demo.ts) it does not work:

```
import Popover from 'popover';
```

First, PhpStorm highlights `popover` with a red line and says `Can not find module 'popover'`. Second, when I build demo with webpack, I got no errors, however build file does not contain the contents of `Popover.ts`.

I do not understand why it happens and how I can fix it.

**Update**: I managed to get rid of red highlighting in PhpStorm by setting `"moduleResolution": "node"` in `tsconfig.json` (thanks to @user254694). However then I got a different problem: build failed. Webpack generated such an error:

```
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for 
F:\dev\js\plugins\popover\demo\npm\node_modules\popover\src\js\Popover.ts. 
By default, ts-loader will not compile .ts files in node_modules.
```

I googled this error and come to the following solution. Add `allowTsInNodeModules` option to `ts-loader`:

```
loader: 'ts-loader',
options: {
   allowTsInNodeModules: true
}
```

Then I added such lines to `tsconfig.js`:

```
"include": [
    "node_modules/popover/src/**/*",
    "node_modules/popover/index.js",
    "node_modules/popover/typings/**/*"
  ]
```

While this eliminated the webpack error and it compiled successfully, I got red highlight again.

**PS**: I generated declaration types in `typings` directory and now my `package.json` looks like this:

```
"main": "index.js",
"types": "typings/index.d.ts",
```

Still wonder how to make it working.

Comment: I'm supposing that when you import it expects a structure in popover.ts similar to the following "export const Popover ...rest of function or whatever" but it sounds like you have require commonjs format - you might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677752/the-difference-between-requirex-and-import-x/46677972

Comment: @user254694 See my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your package should also contain `index.d.ts`. and your `package.json` should have [`types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html#including-declarations-in-your-npm-package) field which points to that file. This will allow importing the package from `node_modules` in typescript.

`index.d.ts` is generated by TypeScript compiler along with `index.js` when [`--declaration`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declaration) compiler option is on. It's off by default, you should add it in `tsconfig.json` file (or command line) if you are going to publish your package with `npm`.

> when I build demo with webpack, I got no errors, however build file does not contain the contents of Popover.ts

This is likely a separate problem. If you are not actually using imported `Popover` in your typescript file, [the compiler will not generate `require` call for that module](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios) as an optimization, so the `Popover.js` will not be included in the bundle. If you are using imported value, it compiles with TypeScript without errors, but generated javascript still does not work, but using that module directly from javascript works - that would be unusual and require more information to solve.

Comment: See my update. I added generated types and added them to package.json

Comment: webpack should use compiled `.js` files from `node_modules` for your `popover` package, just like it does for every other package from `node_modules`. Those `.js` files should be compiled separately as a build step in `popover` package, before you publish it on npm. You have to figure out why webpack is trying to load and compile typescript files from `node_modules` -  this is not the normal way it's supposed work.

Comment: Why not the normal way. I require it - that's why it requires it. The whole question is around this problem. I require `popover` package which has `main` field as index.js, but index.js just exports imported Popover.ts. Read my question again.

Comment: I mean, the require should make webpack to add `.js` file which is already compiled. When you consume `popover` as external module, it's not normal to compile `.ts` files from that module. So, `index.js` should export compiled `Popover.js`, not `.ts`.

Comment: I do not have `Popover.js`, I have only `Popover.ts`. That is the trick. My package is written in typescript.

Comment: When you publish on npm, and your source language is [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928253/writing-npm-modules-in-typescript) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645824/can-i-write-npm-package-in-coffeescript) than javascript, [the consensus seems to be](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+publish+npm+package+written+in+typescript) that source code should be compiled to javascript first, and it's compiled javascript files that should be published. Publishing source code is optional, but for typescript, generated `.d.ts` files should be included too.

Comment: If you want to publish typescript source code only, and make everyone who uses the package to compile from source themselves - you are basically on your own, I don't think anyone has figured out an easy and convenient way to do that.

Comment: I am not aware of it. My goal it to have package with typings where you require my package and have autocomplete etc. You suggest to create `js` folder and compile typescript files there?

Comment: Yes there should be a folder named `js` or `dist` or anything like that, then you have separate `tsconfig.json` in that package with `outDir` set to that folder, `declarations: true`, `module: commonjs`, and compile all sources in the package before publishing. In `package.json`, `main` should point to `js/index.js` which should require `.js` files from that folder. `types` should point to `js/index.d.ts`.  Then when using that package, webpack will bundle compiled `.js` files, and IDEs should follow `types` field in `package.json`, and use `.d.ts` for autocompletion, and type-checking.

Comment: Thanks for such an extensive response. Now I am getting an understanding of how it works.